# Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors: Data path "" must have required property 'outputPath'

Tags: amazon-linux-2

- ng build --aot --build-optimizer

Skipping invalid target value; expected an object.

Project extension with invalid name (serve) found.

Project extension with invalid name (extract-i18n) found.

Project extension with invalid name (test) found.

Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path "" must have required property 'outputPath'.

used to updated my npm and ng.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem ?
I have the same issue